# Create a loop for the script code below the menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used the following code on my site:

```js
let txt_com = document.querySelector(".text_user");
let num_com_user = document.querySelector(".massage_for_user");

txt_com.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.classList.contains("num_com_user")) {
    this.classList = "num_com_user";
    num_com_user.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    this.classList = "num_com_user";
    num_com_user.style.display = "block";
  }

  return;
})
```

```html
<div class="box_main">
  <div class="box-txt">
    <span class="text_user">click</span>
  </div>

  <span class="massage_for_user">No text found!</span>
</div>
```

But this code is executed only once and I have to refresh the page next time. I just want the menu to open or close every time I click on the post.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be setting the `classList` to a string.  The `classList` is an array.

Comment: I clicked you back to zero, but next time please read the indications on how to write a question. 
@Michael M.'s reply does the trick. Bear in mind that your original code didn't do anything on the first click, at least nothing useful for the user, so it was not obvious what solution you were seeking. Next time please write two more lines to better explain your objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's no need for a loop. Don't try to do CSS's job in JavaScript. There's no need to edit the `.style` property when you can just toggle a class instead.

It's better to practice to write a utility class, such as `.hidden` that hides an element, then toggle that class on the element you need to hide/show. Like this:

```js
let txt_com = document.querySelector(".text_user");
let num_com_user = document.querySelector(".massage_for_user");

txt_com.addEventListener("click", function() {
  num_com_user.classList.toggle('hidden');
  
  // any code put here will run every time the menu is clicked
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_main">
  <div class="box-txt">
    <span class="text_user">click</span>
  </div>

  <span class="massage_for_user">No text found!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Michael M. Your code is not working for my site. Please put the script code I wrote in a loop so that every time the user clicks on the post, the script code will be executed.

Comment: @Developer I'm not sure what you're asking. You didn't have any site-specific code in your question and my code uses the same class names. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @Developer Also, using a loop in this situation is a bad idea, as my answer explained. It is better practice to toggle classes and use event listeners.

Comment: I used return to repeat the script code. But the code is executed only once and I have to refresh the page to execute it again. I just want my code to show or hide the sub-menu every time the user clicks on the word.

Comment: @Developer That is exactly what my code is doing in my end. Can you try my code again?

Comment: Your code works fine. The problem was on my side. Thank you very much for your help.